# Trying to ping server from a new laptop

Tags: sql-server, sql

I am trying to connect to a SQL server named instance from a new laptop using SSMS.

I have a desktop where the host is windows 7 and I have a vmware virtual server on this desktop that is running windows nt 6.2 and I have a configured sql server 2012 instance running.

I have SSMS client installed on my windows 7 host and can connect to the sql server fine.
When I try to connect from the ssms client on new laptop (same connection info) I get error.

So I tried pinging the vmware server from new laptop and no reply.
I get a reply from server when I ping from windows 7 desktop.
I can ping from the laptop and get a response from my router.

Please help get my new laptop talking to the server .

Comment: firewall is disabled on both machines

Comment: Have you noticed if the laptop is configured on the same network of your SQL server? I ask because when you install a VM on your desktop a virtual adapter is created to connect the VM (your Windows 8 nt 6.2) to the host (your windows 7) and this connection might be a different network configured automatically by your vmware software and is out of range for the laptop.